# VS Code don't load the user-data

Tags: visual-studio-code, portable-applications

My problem is that the portable version of visual studio code don't load my settings I had copied from the folder `%APPDATA%/code/user`.

I loaded the .zip data and extracted the folder. I added a data folder into the extracted folder of VS Code. It's in `Visual Studio Code\data`. In there i copied the folder "user" from `%APPDATA%/code/` and renamed the user folder into "user-data". Then I started code and the usersettings are not loaded.

The command `.\code.exe --user-directory .\data\user-data` won't work.

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can simply create a folder called `data` in the root folder with
   VS Code.
2. After the startup, the files with standard settings will be
   created in the `data` folder.
3. Then you can just copy the settings from the folder `%AppData%\Code\User` to the folder `data\user-data\User`.
4. To migrate already installed extensions, copy the contents of the `%HomePath%\.vscode\extensions` folder to the `data\extensions` folder.

Comment: My failure was that I copied the data in user-data\  not in user-data\User - thanks for your help

Comment: @KarLito, I understood what was the problem, but decided to fully describe step-by-step preparation for using portable mode

Answer (score 2):

In portable mode, the `--user-directory` command linte option is ignored.

From the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line):

> `--user-data-dir <dir>`
>
> Specifies the directory that user data is kept in, useful when running as root. Has no effect in Portable Mode.

Instead, use the default location of user data for a portable install and copy your user data to that directory (from a previous comment it seems like you've already done so successfuly).

For anyone wishing to use a different user data directory when in portable mode, `symlink`-ing the user data folder should be a viable option if on a linux-like platform.

(Trivia: this was at first [reported as bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63657), after which the documentation was updated, rather making it a feature.)

Comment: very frustrating. they forgot to add that note in `code -h`.